# Ruby Inject Block acting weird?

Tags: ruby, block, inject

I have arrays. Their values are either `0` or a float. I wanted to find out how many non-zero values (hits) there were in my array.

So I used inject for the following. `entry[5]` is where I am storing the number of hits, `entry[6..56]` is where the data are:

```
entry[5] =  entry[6..56].inject {|memo, n| n!=0? memo+=1 : memo+=0}
```

This function works for the most part, but sometimes it returns random values like `340.1`. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please post a snippet with data that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you're missing initial value for the memo

```
entry[6..56].inject(0) {|memo, n| n != 0 ? memo += 1 : memo += 0}
```

If you don't specify initial value, memo will be set to a first element of the sequence. And if it's a float, you'll get a float as a result.

See Arup's answer for more idiomatic solution to your problem.

Comment: `memo += 0` is nonsense (unless you are doing `memo += (n != 0 ? 1 : 0)`, or better `memo += (n.zero? ? 0 : 1)`). `memo` would suffice.

Comment: @sawa: yeah, I know. I made minimal corrections to original code, so that it is recognizable :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I meant to address my comment to all three of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do also the same using [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-count) and [`#nonzero?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Numeric/nonzero%3F):

```
entry[5] = entry[6..56].count(&:nonzero?)
```

Comment: Given that there is `nonzero?`, I guess you liked using `&`.

Comment: @sawa I like the way you guided me really.. Enjoyed it.. :-) Thanks for teaching me..